# How to breathe when tilting ur neck up while swimming

Tags: swimming

I am new to swimming and taking lessons, but I am not able to do "lift my chin up to breathe and go back in", my instructor tells me, just tilt ur neck so when the chin is above water, so u can breathe or keep ur chin above water. I find it very hard to do it and feel like I am failing to do it and if I do, my legs start to sink.

At the moment, I go in the water with a big deep breathe and hold it until I want to breathe again, for which I had to stand up, as I tried to lift by the neck up, I get chocked by water